# Using anchor tags to load php

Tags: php

How can I use **anchor tags to load a certain php function**?

Such as the default php function is **Firstpage()**; and that function loads a list of links, such as **Secondpage and Thirdpage**, in which direct to domain.com/index.php#secondpage and etc

To cut it short (I didnt really finish the top part, sorry), how can I make it so if the link is #secondpage, load the secondpage function, whilst not having firstpage loaded unless the domain has no anchor tags?

Or is there another way?

Sorry for this, Its hard for me to explain :P

Comment: Or, if this is not possible, having the <a></a> load a function in php

Comment: ajax and rest api will be good solution for this...

Comment: All comes out the same: you either use rewriting on http server level (apache) or you have a central controller file which parses the request uri and acts accordingly (typical on nginx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in plain PHP. Javascript will also be needed for that.

> Or is there another way?

Yes

> Or, if this is not possible, having the  load a function in php

Simple, use query string values. For example

```
<a href="test.php?function=1">test 1</a>
```

Then in PHP you can do

```
if(isset($_GET['function'])){
    $function=intval($function);
    if($function==1){
          //call first page function here
    }
    elseif($function==2){
          //call second page function here
    }
}
else{
     //since we got no indication from the URL, we can show default page here.
}
```

Comment: The normal part works, except for when function does equal 1, it doesnt echo anything

Comment: Thanks for this, I have changed your script around a bit so I dont have to do if function==*, but now the $function equals what the php gets from my database.